# How to open Excel file on fullscreen by default?

Tags: macos, ms-office

I have MacBooks running macOS Monterey and macOS Sierra.

Users send me Excel files through a network folder.

When I open those Excel files, I want them to be opened maximized (full screen) by default.

I tried unchecking Close Apps while quitting in System Preferences. I tried to save Excel in Fullscreen and reopen.

Both of these methods did not help. Can anyone help me to figure out this?

One more thing: some users' Excel files (sent through network folder) open in maximized, but most of user's Excel files open in the normal window.